# How to bind data retrieved from Azure Mobile Services to GridView dynamically?

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app

Using Azure Mobile Services to retrieve data from my Azure SQL DB, i would like to display those in my Employees gridview.

Here is my XAML code :

```
<GridView Name="Employees" SelectionMode="Single" Width="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItemStyle}" SelectionChanged="Employees_SelectionChanged">
    <GridViewItem Name="EmployeeNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="140,50,0,0">
        <StackPanel Name="ProfilePicAndDetails" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Image  Name="ProfilePic" Source="Assets/profilepic.png"  Height="140" Width="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
            <StackPanel Name="Details" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Margin="40,-10,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Name="DisplayName" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                    <TextBox Name="LastName" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="-10,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBox Name="Login" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                <TextBox Name="Phone" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                <TextBox Name="Mail" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                <StackPanel Name="OtherDetails" Margin="-190,10,0,0">
                    <TextBox Name="Title" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                    <TextBox Name="Department" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                    <TextBox Name="Manager" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

My code behind retrieving data :

```
var GetEmployeesTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<GetEmployee>();
var FoundEmployees = await GetEmployeesTable.Where(g => g.givenName == GivenName && g.surname == SurName).ToListAsync();
```

I have 9 fieds in my DB :

givenName, surname, mail, phone, title, department, managerName, domainName, sAMAccountName.

The goal is to bind each of those fileds following this way :

1. givenName (DB) -> FirstName (gridview)
2. surname (DB) -> LastName (gridview)
3. ... (and so on) ...

I am successfully retrieving data from my Azure SQL DB using Azure Mobile Services but can't see how to bind them dynamically to my gridview.

NB : I could have multiple employees to display (means multiple gridview items to create dynamically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the binding for the Text property in XAML code. Seems like you forgot this: 
Eg:

```
 <TextBox Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding givenName}"
```

Besides this you have to set the data source for your GridView.

Check out this post. It explains your scenario pretty good: 
http://debugmode.net/2013/04/11/fetching-windows-azure-mobile-services-data-in-xaml-based-windows-store-application/

Comment: Daniel, Thank you. Your link provides a great exemple. I didn't know that i could retrieve my data as a collection and bind them to my gridview directly.